Said Nacheim on Tisha B'Av maariv or shachris
Per Rema 557:1

הגה והמנהג פשוט שאין אומרים נחם רק בתפלת מנחה של תשעה באב לפי שאז הציתו אש במקדש ולכן מתפללים אז על נחמה (רוקח ואבודרהם) מי שאכל בט"ב יאמר נחם בברכת המזון (מהרי"ל):
Rema Note: The simple custom is not to say Nachem except during the Minchah prayer on Tisha be-Av, for it was then {in the afternoon} that the fire took hold in the Mikdash, and therefore we pray at this time about the consolation (Rohach, Avudrahum). One who ate on Tisha be-Av, would say "Nachem" {instead of "Rachem"} in Grace after meals (Maharil)

What is the halacha if someone mistakenly said it in Mariv or shachris of Tisha Beav, does shemone esreh have to be repeated?

The majority of rishonim and the simple reading of the earliest sources would say you did the right thing.

What makes you think there would be a need to do anything besides finish the amida?

@Dude see MB 108:38

@Dude He's not assuming it's a hefsek; he's asking if it is a hefsek.

This article discusses the case of someone mistakenly saying Nachem on 17 Tammuz, concluding it's not a problem. Even according to the opinion that adding a mention of the wrong day would normally be an interruption, the ruination of the Beis Hamikdash is always true and relevant, to the extent that some had a custom of saying it throughout the year, so Nachem would never constitute an interruption. All the reasoning and citations brought there seem equally applicable to your scenario, and perhaps more so, considering the opinions that it's appropriate to say it in every prayer on 9 Av. So there would be no reason to repeat it.

As the Rama states its only the custom, implying that one can do all 3 prayers according to halacha (as many s'fardim do), he also doesn't specify in the "sister bracha" Rachem in Birkat Hamazon to just say it Mincha time (afternoon). Using the principle of Safek brachot l'hakel, it would seem that even according to the Rama it is fine since it is just a minhag to do Mincha but halachically it applies the whole day.
Even the whole year, the Rambam writes regarding the  that you have multiple options for the ending the bracha in Birkat Hamazon (B'rachot 2:4-5), implying they should all be fine in the Amida.
Bonus: if you say Hamelech or HaEl Hamishpat during the year you don't have to repeat (Mishna Brurah 118:3).

None of these implications are very compelling. When the rama says והמנהג he doesn't always mean "but the other way is fine too", he's just describing the practice in his area. Also because Rambam allows two versions of bentching doesn't necessarily imply even Rambam let alone anyone holds of two versions in davening or that this change is equivalent to the other version.

Safek Brachos doesn't help since you can always daven again as nedava (assuming of course there is any safek)

ashkenazim tend to stay away from nedava. quick search shows sabal does apply in amida too https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.118.1.1?vhe=Kaf_Hachayim,_Orach_Chayim_vol._I-IV,_Jerusalem_1910-1933&lang=he

That's talking about a random nedava not when it's fulfilling some halachic doubt. The laws of tashlumin are full of "daven again al tnai it may be a nedava"

even for halachic doubt once we pasken its ok bediavad but either way there are sources that sabal apply in amida like by hamelech hamishpat

Yes, some (not all) apply it in the middle of the amida (do you go back to the bracha if you're still in the middle), but not to after you finished and consider praying again.
